# How do I dynamically sum input values inside a repeatable fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get total of dynamically created each fields value

```
    <div class="rf-row count-container">
        <input class="total">
            <div class="row">
                <input class="add-monthly">
            </div>
           <div class="row">
                <input class="add-monthly">
           </div>
           <div class="row">
                <input class="add-monthly">
           </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried in order to solve your problem first. If you run into any issues then in SO we can look at specifics.

Comment: For those answering, could you please take the time to explain your solutions in order that the OP, and future visitors, can learn from you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code this may help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  Demo
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="rf-row count-container">
    <input class="total">
        <div class="row">
            <input class="add-monthly" value="5">
        </div>
       <div class="row">
            <input class="add-monthly" value="5">
       </div>
       <div class="row">
            <input class="add-monthly" value="5">
       </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var value = 0;
    $('.count-container .row').each(function(){
      value += parseInt($(this).find('.add-monthly').val()) ? parseInt($(this).find('.add-monthly').val()) : 0
    })
   $('.total').val(value);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

check below link
    https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdpZpR?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `jquery` tagged, the following is the way you'd iterate over all your `input`s of class `add-monthly` and sum their values together, finally returning the sum value:

```
function sumFields() {
    var totalSum = 0;
    $("input.add-monthly").each(function () {
        totalSum += $(this).val();
    });
    return totalSum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('add-monthly')
classes = [...classes]
var result = classes
                   .map(item => +item.value)
                   .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

document.getElementsByClassName('sum-monthly')[0].value = result 

console.log('summ', result)
```

```html
 <div class="rf-row count-container">
            SUM: <input class="sum-monthly"/><br/>
            <div class="sub-rf-row">
                <input class="add-monthly" type="number" value="1">
            </div>
           <div class="sub-rf-row">
                <input class="add-monthly" type="number" value="4">
           </div>
           <div class="sub-rf-row template">
                <input class="add-monthly" type="number" value="0">
           </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `SUM` is not changing on value change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding `input` fields, I would suggest delegating the change functionality to the parent `.count-container`. Once the event is triggered, I am iterating over the `.add-monthly` fields to sum up their values. To help `JavaScript` understand that these values are floats (since I assume we are dealing with a currency), I am using [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to insure the value can be added to the sum. Lastly, I am setting the value of `.sum-monthly` to use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format a number using a fixed-point notation (again I am assuming we are dealing with a currency).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.count-container').on('change', '.add-monthly', function() {
    let total = 0;
    $('.add-monthly').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    $('.sum-monthly').val(total.toFixed(2));
  }).find('.add-monthly').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rf-row count-container">
  <input class="sum-monthly" readonly>
  <div class="sub-rf-row">
    <input class="add-monthly">
  </div>
  <div class="sub-rf-row">
    <input class="add-monthly">
  </div>
  <div class="sub-rf-row template">
    <input class="add-monthly">
  </div>
</div>
```